# is $I^2=I$ true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $I$ is an ideal of a ring with $1$. I think that $II=I^2=I$ but I am stuck showing it. I can easily show that $I^2\subseteq I$, but I dont know how to show that $I\subseteq I^2$. So is it actually true? If yes, how can I show it?

Definition of $I^2=\{\sum_{k=1}^m x_k y_k: m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}, x_k,y_k\in I\}$

Comment: No, consider for example the ideal $I =(2)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. You can show that $I^2 = (4)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Counterexample:

$$I=\langle\;x\;\rangle\le\Bbb Z[x]\;,\;\;\text{but}\;I^2=\langle\;x^2\;\rangle \ne\langle\;x\;\rangle$$

Comment: This was actually the problem: Suppose $I$ and $J$ are ideals of a ring $R$ with 1 such that $I+J=R$. I have to prove that also $I^2+J^2=R$. But I am stuck now.

Comment: Oh, well: what's *way* another matter. We assume the ring is commutative: $$R=R^3=\left(I+J\right)^3\subset I^2+J^2$$

Can you see why the inclusion there? (Apply Newton's Binomial Theorem...) . In fact, it is true that $\,I^n+J^m=R\;\;\forall\,n,m\in\Bbb N\;$

Answer (score 2):

If you original problem is to show that $I+ J = R$ implies that $I^2 + J^2 = R$, consider what your assumption says. It says there are $a \in I$ and $b \in J$ so that $a+b = 1$. Cubing you get that $a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + b^3 = 1$, viz $a^2(a + 3b) + b^2(3a + b) = 1$. Notice that $a^2 \in I^2$ and $b^2 \in J^2$ so you are done.